# Store and retrieve HTML in Mongo (i.e. using <span> to format text pulled from DB)

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, materialize

I'm using Meteor and I have a template that retrieves text from Mongo and displays it in a [Materialize `<p class="flow-text">`](http://materializecss.com/typography.html). However, I would like to apply some formatting to this text, so I have stored it in the database with HTML tags e.g.:

```
...
"questionText" : "This question contains a <span class=\"excel-formula\">=formula</span>"
...
```

However when I display this text using a template is just writes out the `<span....` tag on the screen as text rather than applying it as an HTML tag.

How can I make it apply the HTML tags rather than treating them as string literals?

In my `<template name="Question">` the relevant lines are:

```
<p class="flow-text">
    {{questionText}}
</p>
```

And I'm calling the template

```
  {{#each questions}}
    {{#if getSessionVariable "submitted"}}
      {{> Result}}
    {{else}}
      {{> Question}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

where `questions` is

```
  Template.Test.helpers({
    questions: function () {
      var Q = Tests.findOne({"name":Session.get("testName")});
      return Q.questions;
    }
  });
```

and `Tests` is my mongo collection `Tests = new Mongo.Collection("tests");`

Comment: Use `Spacebars.SafeString`.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert thanks, your comment lead me to https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-return-html-tag-from-template-helper/2791 and I see that if I use triple braces (i.e. `{{{questionText}}}`) then it works! Is there a difference between `{{{}}}` and `Spacebars.SafeString`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the triple mustache to ensure content is put in 'as is', only `<script>` code will be ignored.

```
<p class="flow-text">
    {{{questionText}}}
</p>
```

Comment: Do we need to take in consideration the security aspect here, since any arbitrary content will be evaluated as code?